# Unexpected behavior with case_when and is.na

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to change all NA values in a column to 0 and all other values to 1. However, I can't get the combination of case_when and is.na to work.

```
# Create dataframe
a <- c(rep(NA,9), 2, rep(NA, 10))
b <- c(rep(NA,9), "test", rep(NA, 10))
df <- data.frame(a,b, stringsAsFactors = F)

# Create new column (c), where all NA values in (a) are transformed to 0 and other values are transformed to 1
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(
    c = case_when(
      a == is.na(.$a) ~ 0,
      FALSE ~ 1
    )
  )
```

I expect column (c) to indicate all 0 values and one 1 value, but its all 0's.

It does work when I use an if_else statement with is.na, like:

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(
    c = if_else(is.na(a), 0, 1))
  )
```

What is going on here?

Comment: Since you're using `mutate`, you can (and should) point to the column `a` without `.$a`. The `a == is.na(a)` part doesn't really make sense, since `is.na` returns a logical and `a` is numeric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be doing this instead:

```
df %>% 
    mutate(
        c = case_when(
            is.na(a) ~ 0,
            TRUE ~ 1
        )
    )
```